# How do you see what packages are available for update

Tags: package-management, updates

FreeBSD user joining your ranks.  I've been asked to look after an Ubuntu Server running 10.04 LTS.

I see from `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available` that there are a number of updates on the server however I do not see a way to tell which will be updated.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction so as I can see which packages will get updated when I run `apt-get upgrade`?

**UPDATE:**

Can't answer my own question at the moment so throwing this in here for the time being:

Along with the `apt-get upgrade --dry-run` suggested below, 
`/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p` will list all packages that have updates available.

Comment: Welcome to the ranks, use and abuse the site if you need further help ;) If you find an answer that satisfies your question please mark it with the green check box next to it.

Comment: You should now be able to answer your own question since that you have enough rep to [remove new user restrictions](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user).

Comment: looks like it's 100rep required or an 8hour wait to answer your own question.

Comment: In 2016, the answer given by @doru is spot on. http://askubuntu.com/a/788049/560610

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could install `aptitude` if it isn't already installed. It's a great tool for managing packages in a headless setup.

[image]

Otherwise if you just want to see what's going to happen when you run something, use the `--dry-run` argument and it won't actually do anything, it'll just tell you what it *would* do:

From the [apt-get man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man8/apt-get.8.html)

> ```
> -s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
>           No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur but do
>           not actually change the system. Configuration Item:
>           APT::Get::Simulate.
>
>           Simulate prints out a series of lines each one representing a dpkg
>           operation, Configure (Conf), Remove (Remv), Unpack (Inst). Square
>           brackets indicate broken packages with and empty set of square
>           brackets meaning breaks that are of no consequence (rare).
> ```

Add the option to the command this way

```
apt upgrade --dry-run
```

Comment: I disfigured your answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Interestingly `apt-get upgrade --dry-run` doesn't require `sudo`, which makes it perfect for an automated display of required package updates.

Comment: even more interesting is, that on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "apt-get -s update" doesn't accept "-s"... nor "--dry-run", "--no-act"... why would that be?

Comment: @mBardos Have you replaced the `apt-get` in your path with a "helper" script? Check `which apt-get` to make sure it's `/usr/bin/apt-get`

Comment: martonb@martonb-ubu:~/work/qt$ which apt-get
    /usr/bin/apt-get
  
Does this work for you on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

    martonb@martonb-ubu:~/work/qt$ apt-get -s update
    E: Command line option 's' [from -s] is not known.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` when you use `--dry-run`.

Answer (score 112):

As of now (Ubuntu 16.04) you can use `apt list` with the `--upgradable` flag;

```
sudo apt update
apt list --upgradable
```

and you will get a list with all upgradable packages.

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I wanted to see :)

Comment: `apt` is unknown command in 12.04

Comment: @confiq ["APT 1.0 was released on the 1. April 2014"](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/), so is possible to not being upgraded on your system. Try to see which version of `apt` you have installed running `sudo apt-cache policy apt`.

Comment: that explains...

Answer (score 12):

Below command will show you the list of installed packages which has an update available in the repositories.

```
dpkg --get-selections | xargs apt-cache policy {} | grep -1 Installed | sed -r 's/(:|Installed: |Candidate: )//' | uniq -u | tac | sed '/--/I,+1 d' | tac | sed '$d' | sed -n 1~2p
```

Comment: That's a nice bit of command line magic!

Comment: Nice, but @sierrasdetandil’s and @doru’ answers do exactly the same in a beautifully concise way...

Comment: Yes, but aptitude is an additional install and apt doesn't like to be scripted.

Comment: @Avinash Raj Did you mean to include `--ignore-case` or `-i` instead of `1` at the command pipe segment `grep -1 Installed `? Did you mean `-A 1` by any chance, because they have the same output! I wonder about this behavior and whether there was a placeholding variable flag for grep that can be substituted directly with a number!

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative would be to use `aptitude` with a [search term](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04.html):

```
aptitude search '~U'
```

(Note the uppercase 'U')

That means: "search for all packages that are installed and can be upgraded". Reference: [aptitude user's manual](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html#searchUpgradable)

By default, `aptitude search` shows for each package its name, description and a few flags, but you could also adapt the output to your needs. For example, to list only the package names, the command would be:

```
aptitude search -F '%p' --disable-columns '~U'
```

(`--disable-columns` avoids padding whitespace at the end of the lines)